# How to exclude .class files from file search in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, file, class, search

I want eclipse to ignore all .class files when I search for a keyword in files. I don't want a particular directory to be excluded, instead I want to exclude all files of type .class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you open the File Search in Eclipse, there is a text box for filename patterns.  You can enter the patterns you DO want to include, like `*.java, *.xml`, etc. (each pattern separated by a comma) , and it will only search in files of that type.

EDIT:
To exclude a file type, place an exclamation mark in front of the pattern, like

```
!*.class, !*.svn
```

Comment: My main purpose is to do a full search and want to exclude unnecessary searches in .class, .svn files so that the full search works faster. I tried the resource filter in Project > Properties > Resource > Resource Filters which didn't work. If someone can provide the exact setting for excluding a particular type of file in Resource filter that would be helpful.

Comment: There is already an option 'Exclude all' in Resource filter. I am looking for the settings in resource filter so that I don't need to worry about   unwanted files in eclipse anymore. If there is an option to post screenshots i could have explained in more detail. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to exclude files of a specific extension in eclipse using resource filters:

- Right-click on the project in project explorer -> select properties
- Expand the Resource heading on the left of the properties window and select Resource filters
- Select the Add Filter button

In my scenario, I was ignoring tar.gz archives:

[image]

So in this example *.class could have been inputted rather than *.tar.gz to ignore all files with the class extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Working Set pointing it to your java source dir,
and select it on Open Resource (Ctrl+Shift R normally)

[Open Resource window Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf5LA.png)

[menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRmci.png)

The working set will be remembered when you open it again.